# ¿Qué significa "can’t assign to operator function call"?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

El error “SyntaxError: can’t assign to operator function call”  no se genera cuando intenta evaluar una declaración matemática antes que un operador de asignación.

Para corregir este error, debemos asegurarnos de que todos los nombres de las variables aparezcan en el lado izquierdo de un operador de asignación y que todas las declaraciones matemáticas aparezcan a la derecha.

En este caso, en el que intento introducir valores calculados con datos de columnas de un Dataframe, utilizando el método "at", ¿Cuál puede ser la causa de este error?.

```
# Importar cotizaciones de un único ISIN
import os
import pandas as pd
url = "https://funds.ddns.net/f.php?isin=" + "ES0114638036"
df = pd.read_html(url, header=0, thousands="", parse_dates=True,  decimal="," )[0]
df.columns = (["Date", "Close"])
df = df.set_index("Date")

df= df.dropna(inplace = True)

 # Inicializa vacía la columna del dataframe
df["ROC"] = ''
df["ROC"] = pd.to_numeric(df1["ROC"])
for i in range (0, df.shape[0]-9):
    df.at(i, "ROC") = ((df.iloc[i, 0] - df.iloc[i+9, 0]) / df.iloc[i+9, 0])*100
    #((df.iloc[i, 0] - df.iloc[i+9, 0]) / df.iloc[i+9, 0])*100 = df.at(i, "ROC")     
df[:3]
```

La aplicación del método "df.at(i, "ROC")", no se puede entender como la variable?.

Comment: ¿No será `df.at[i, "ROC"] `? Si usas paréntesis, estás ejecutando una función; si usas `[]` estás accesando una celda, la que puedes leer o cambiar su contenido.

Comment: Efectivamente, lleva [ ]. Gracias. ¿Elimino la pregunta?, quizás no aporta nada a los demás.

Comment: No la elimines. Creo que da para una respuesta valiosa.

Comment: Gracias. Me aclara algunos conceptos y me orienta a intentar profundizar en otros, como la vectorización en python.